# SOQL non-selective query: avoid IsDeleted field

Tags: salesforce

I have the following exception with my trigger:  System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large object type (more than 100000 rows).  The query used in the trigger is:

```html
SELECT Id, Type__c, Assembled__c, Production_Center__c,Transport_to__c, Quality_Control_Result__c, Quality_Control_Date__c 
  FROM OLI_Core__c 
  WHERE Production_Center__c = :centerId 
  ORDER BY Quality_Control_Date__c DESC LIMIT 8000
```

**Production_Center__c** field cannot be null and is a lookup, so it is indexed.  Then, I tried to run the query in the developer consol (replacing **:centerId** with a value) and the query plan give a **cost** around 6.5 at **Index as Leading Operation Type**.

The query plan note this: "*Not considering filter for optimization because unindexed. Table: OLI_Core__c Fields: ["IsDeleted"]*".  **IsDeleted** is a standard and boolean field, I think it cannot be custom indexed and I also think this is not a good idea even if that is possible.

So, is there any solution to get a cost **bellow 1** at Index Leading Operation Type according to the IsDeleted field problem.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I have solved this problem by using CreatedDate (which is indexed by default) and getting all recent records. Then I use IF statement to filter the result.
This workaround is used until my request to Salesforce about custom indexing will be done.